# Consolidate two rows in a SQL Table based on timestamp and an boolean

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, mariadb, sql-insert

Out of "historic" reason i have following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `measurement`
(
        `measureID`     int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
        `terraID`       int NOT NULL ,
        `pinID`         int NOT NULL ,
        `time`          timestamp NOT NULL ,
        `value`         float NULL ,
        `temperature`   boolean NOT NULL ,

        PRIMARY KEY (`measureID`),
        KEY `measure_terraID_FK` (`terraID`),
        KEY `measure_pinID_FK` (`pinID`),
        CONSTRAINT `measure_terraID_reference` FOREIGN KEY `measure_terraID_FK` (`terraID`) REFERENCES `terrarium` (`terraID`),
        CONSTRAINT `measure_pinID_reference` FOREIGN KEY `measure_pinID_FK` (`pinID`) REFERENCES `pins` (`pinID`)
) ENGINE=INNODB COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

```
| measureID | terraID | pinID | time                | value  | temperature |
|:----------|---------|-------|---------------------|--------|------------:|
|         1 |       1 |     9 | 2020-04-10 13:00:01 |   34.3 |           0 |
|         2 |       1 |     9 | 2020-04-10 13:00:01 |   26.5 |           1 |
|         3 |       2 |    10 | 2020-04-10 13:00:01 |   35.1 |           0 |
|         4 |       2 |    10 | 2020-04-10 13:00:01 |   32.9 |           1 |
|         5 |       1 |     9 | 2020-04-10 13:05:01 |   34.4 |           0 |
|         6 |       1 |     9 | 2020-04-10 13:05:01 |   26.6 |           1 |
|         7 |       2 |    10 | 2020-04-10 13:05:01 |     35 |           0 |
|         8 |       2 |    10 | 2020-04-10 13:05:01 |     33 |           1 |
[...]
|     38087 |       2 |    10 | 2020-08-31 12:50:02 |   35.9 |           0 |
|     38088 |       2 |    10 | 2020-08-31 12:50:02 |     35 |           1 |
|     38089 |       1 |    11 | 2020-08-31 12:50:02 | 25.187 |           1 |
|     38090 |       2 |    12 | 2020-08-31 12:50:02 | 28.312 |           1 |
|     38091 |       2 |    10 | 2020-08-31 12:55:01 |   35.8 |           0 |
|     38092 |       2 |    10 | 2020-08-31 12:55:01 |     35 |           1 |
|     38093 |       1 |    11 | 2020-08-31 12:55:01 |  25.25 |           1 |
|     38094 |       2 |    12 | 2020-08-31 12:55:01 | 28.375 |           1 |
```

and want that to be inserted into a new table, based on time and pinID, so that the final table looks like that:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `measurement`
(
        `measureID`     int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
        `terraID`       int NOT NULL ,
        `pinID`         int NOT NULL ,
        `time`          timestamp NOT NULL ,
        `temperature`   float NULL ,
        `humidity`      float NULL ,

        PRIMARY KEY (`measureID`),
        KEY `measure_terraID_FK` (`terraID`),
        KEY `measure_pinID_FK` (`pinID`),
        CONSTRAINT `measure_terraID_reference` FOREIGN KEY `measure_terraID_FK` (`terraID`) REFERENCES `terrarium` (`terraID`),
        CONSTRAINT `measure_pinID_reference` FOREIGN KEY `measure_pinID_FK` (`pinID`) REFERENCES `pins` (`pinID`)
) ENGINE=INNODB COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

```
| measureID | terraID | pinID | time                | temperature | humidity |
|:----------|---------|-------|---------------------|--------------|---------:|
|         2 |       1 |     9 | 2020-04-10 13:00:01 |         26.5 |     34.3 |
|         4 |       2 |    10 | 2020-04-10 13:00:01 |         32.9 |     35.1 |
|         6 |       1 |     9 | 2020-04-10 13:05:01 |         26.6 |     34.4 |
|         8 |       2 |    10 | 2020-04-10 13:05:01 |           33 |       35 |
[...]
|     38088 |       2 |    10 | 2020-08-31 12:50:02 |           35 |     35.9 |
|     38089 |       1 |    11 | 2020-08-31 12:50:02 |       25.187 |     NULL |
|     38090 |       2 |    12 | 2020-08-31 12:50:02 |       28.312 |     NULL |
|     38092 |       2 |    10 | 2020-08-31 12:55:01 |           35 |     35.8 |
|     38093 |       1 |    11 | 2020-08-31 12:55:01 |        25.25 |     NULL |
|     38094 |       2 |    12 | 2020-08-31 12:55:01 |       28.375 |     NULL |
```

My SQL Version is mariadb-10.3

I don't want to lose any values and I don't care for the temperature column, because it's an old identifier in how to read the value. But I want to modify all old entries to be transformed to the new structure.
But you can use it in IF(temperature=1, value, NULL) as temperature, IF(temperature=0, value, '') as humidity or somewhat.

The terraID and pinID are keyed to other tables and not all sensors deliver temperature and humidity.

I have no luck with some insert into select subquerie magic... maybe I'm too dumb to wrap my head around the problem.

Can you possibly lead me to the correct function. It's just a once-triggered manual job.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What is your version of MySql/MariaDB?

Comment: mariadb-10.3 on a raspbian.

Comment: Do you want a new different table?

Comment: it seems it is easier to make a new table and replace it later, which i can do no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    min(measureID), 
    terraID, 
    pinID, 
    time, 
    max(case when temperature = 1 then value end) value,
    max(case when temperature = 0 then value end) humidity
from mytable
group by terraID, pinID, time
order by min(measureID)
```

If needed, you can easily turn this to an `insert` query (using `insert ... select ...`) or even to a `create table` statement (`create table newtable as ...`).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=48fd87681b18fcd1e8e7a0b2156fc56c)**:

```
measureID | terraID | pinID | time                |  value | humidity
--------: | ------: | ----: | :------------------ | -----: | -------:
        2 |       1 |     9 | 2020-04-10 13:00:01 | 26.500 |   34.300
        4 |       2 |    10 | 2020-04-10 13:00:01 | 32.900 |   35.100
        6 |       1 |     9 | 2020-04-10 13:05:01 | 26.600 |   34.400
        8 |       2 |    10 | 2020-04-10 13:05:01 | 33.000 |   35.000
    38088 |       2 |    10 | 2020-08-31 12:50:02 | 35.000 |   35.900
    38089 |       1 |    11 | 2020-08-31 12:50:02 | 25.187 |     null
    38090 |       2 |    12 | 2020-08-31 12:50:02 | 28.312 |     null
    38092 |       2 |    10 | 2020-08-31 12:55:01 | 35.000 |   35.800
    38093 |       1 |    11 | 2020-08-31 12:55:01 | 25.250 |     null
    38094 |       2 |    12 | 2020-08-31 12:55:01 | 28.375 |     null
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that was not my immediate Problem. The select when cases are known to me.
It gives me this output:
```
|     38083 |       2 |    10 | 2020-08-31 12:45:01 |        NULL |     35.9 |
|     38084 |       2 |    10 | 2020-08-31 12:45:01 |        34.8 |     NULL |
```
But i wanted them to be merged into a sweet oneliner:
```
|     38084 |       2 |    10 | 2020-08-31 12:45:01 |        34.8 |     35.9 |
```

Comment: @ShenLong: doesn't this query produces the results that you want?

Comment: Not exactly. It does fill the columns with the correct values, but i wanted also that the rows which have the same pinID and timestamp are consolidated. i'm sorry that on mariadb-10.3 your solution seems not to work here.

Comment: @ShenLong: ah, I see, I had one unecessary column in the `group by` clause. I fixed that, and also added a db fiddle for your reference.

Comment: That is working, but i had to put an round(max(),2) in that. So that my temperature dont get bloated into 10 decimals, which i dont need. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEAD()` window function:

```
INSERT INTO new_measurement(measureID, terraID, pinID, time, temperature, humidity)
SELECT measureID, terraID, pinID, time, 
       CASE temperature WHEN 1 THEN value END, 
       value
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
         LEAD(terraID) OVER (ORDER BY time DESC) next_terraID,
         LEAD(pinID) OVER (ORDER BY time DESC) next_pinID
  FROM measurement 
) t  
WHERE terraID <> next_terraID OR pinID <> next_pinID
```